# Older Characters

Tags: fiction, characters

I'm ten years old and writing a book series. I have trouble writing about older characters, and that's especially the older kids that are already dating. I don't know any people that could help me write for those characters. Do you have any advice on making those characters more realistic?

Comment: Just a friendly warning: [people under 13 (under 16 in the EU) aren't allowed to have Stack Exchange accounts, due to legal issues regarding data retention](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age). I'm not going to snitch on you, I'm just letting you know in case your account does get deleted and you're left wondering why.

Comment: @F1Krazy If I suddenly lose the 45 rep I've gained from this question, I'll know why I guess :(

Comment: @MicahWindsor Not to worry, this question will still remain here even if OP's account does get deleted. Account deletion doesn't delete questions and answers unless they're negatively scored, which this one isn't.

Comment: [This question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2959/writing-about-drug-induced-hallucinations-and-paranoia), [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18952/how-to-write-about-an-emotion-you-never-experienced) and [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/39139/writing-about-a-topic-which-you-dont-have-personal-experience-in) may all contain answers applicable to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice? Write what you know. My little brother is 10 and I can't imagine him writing an accurate story about teenage romance. If you are intent on writing an entire *series* at your age, I strongly encourage you to write for a young audience.

That being said, a story told from the point of view of a 10-year-old about what they observe of the lives of the "older kids" could use some vague, humorously ill-informed descriptions. For example:

> *I saw an older boy and a girl the same age just sitting next to each other talking, and the next time I looked, he was trying to bite her neck like a vampire and had one of his hands... well... somewhere hands aren't supposed to be! I ran all the way to the other side of the school to tell the principal that a student was being eaten, but he didn't believe me. Grown-ups.*

By the way, just because you're writing about older characters doesn't mean they have to date. I'm 18 (almost done Grade 12) and I've never been on a real date. I don't have my own car, and I basically spend all my time either working at the grocery store or doing schoolwork or scrolling through StackExchange websites like this one. In other words, I don't have very much time for romance.

Basically, I see two options:

1. Write about young characters and make them realistic.
2. Write about older characters and expect people to laugh (in a good way) at your intentionally imperfect descriptions.

Either way, I wish you luck!

Comment: Some characters are dating for plot purposes. This is good advice. I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

When I was your age I wrote about older people. I just watched what older people did and noted that I didn't understand why. Maybe read some books where the main character is your age, and see how they handle it. You might have to go to the library to get some. The list of ones I know isn't very good, but here are a couple of leads. Good Luck! Many great writers started out writing when they were your age, like Dr. Isaac Asimov. Just don't get discouraged...you have plenty of time to write! I started writing at 11, and I am still doing it many years later. Some magazines for kids take submissions by kids. Check that out, too.

https://imaginationsoup.net/best-books-10-year-olds/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_books_written_by_children_or_teenagers